# Populating Pandas DataFrame column based on dictionary of regex

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
    GE    GO
1   AD    Weiss
2   KI    Ruby
3   OH    Port
4   ER    Rose
5   KI    Rose
6   JJ    Weiss
7   OH    7UP
8   AD    7UP
9   OP    Coke
10  JJ    Stout
```

and I'm trying to add one more column  based on the value of of column `GO`. I was thinking about using a dictionary, but I need to use regex to identify partial matches in my real case. For instance:

```
Dic={'Weiss|\wuby|Sto\w+':'Beer', 'Port|Rose':'Wine','\dUP|Coke':'Soda'}
```

This would give

```
    GE    GO    OUT
1   AD    Weiss Beer
2   KI    Ruby  Beer
3   OH    Port  Wine
4   ER    Rose  Wine
5   KI    Rose  Wine
6   JJ    Weiss Beer
7   OH    7UP   Soda
8   AD    7UP   Soda
9   OP    Coke  Soda
10  JJ    Stout Beer
```

Would a lambda function work here? How would I make it into regex? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
In [253]: df['OUT'] = df[['GO']].replace({'GO':Dic}, regex=True)

In [254]: df
Out[254]:
    GE     GO   OUT
1   AD  Weiss  Beer
2   KI   Ruby  Beer
3   OH   Port  Wine
4   ER   Rose  Wine
5   KI   Rose  Wine
6   JJ  Weiss  Beer
7   OH    7UP  Soda
8   AD    7UP  Soda
9   OP   Coke  Soda
10  JJ  Stout  Beer
```

**Intereseting observation** - in older Pandas versions, `Series.map()` method was almost always faster compared to `DataFrame.replace()` and `Series.str.replace()` methods. It got better in Pandas 0.19.2:

```
In [267]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [268]: %timeit df.GO.map(lambda x: next(Dic[k] for k in Dic if re.search(k, x)))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.57 s per loop

In [269]: %timeit df[['GO']].replace({'GO':Dic}, regex=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 895 ms per loop

In [270]: %timeit df.GO.replace(Dic, regex=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 876 ms per loop

In [271]: df.shape
Out[271]: (100000, 2)
```

Comment: Ahh. Nice use of `replace`.

Comment: No WAI!... awesome  BTW `df.GO.replace(Dic, regex=True)`

Comment: Thank you guys! I think @Psidom's solution will be faster... ;-)

Comment: What happens when one value matches more than one regex?

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: @piRSquared, the first one in dictionary will win

Comment: @piRSquared, please post `df.GO.replace(Dic, regex=True)` as your own solution - it definitely worth it!

Comment: @MaxU I appreciate it... But feels way too much like your answer :-)

Comment: @piRSquared, i've added a timing - your method is the fastest one ;-)

Answer (score 5):

One option is to make use of `re` module with a `map` on the `GO` column:

```
import re
df['OUT'] = df.GO.map(lambda x: next(Dic[k] for k in Dic if re.search(k, x)))
df
```

[image]

This raises error if none of the pattern matches the string. If there are cases where string doesn't match any pattern, you can write a custom function to capture the exception and return None:

```
import re
def findCat(x):
    try:
        return next(Dic[k] for k in Dic if re.search(k, x))
    except:
        return None

df['OUT'] = df.GO.map(findCat)
df
```

Comment: This is sorta what I was thinking... but hadn't gotten nearly far enough.

Comment: @piRSquared Obviously, MaxU has a better way for this.

Comment: I'm really surprised - in previous versions `DF.replace()` and `Series.str.replace()` was always slower compared to `Series.map()` - in Pandas 0.19.2 for this particular case for DF with 30.000 rows it's not the case!

Comment: It could be due to the lambda used in the `map`, which also invokes `regex` matches which might slow things down.