# How to improve performance with looping dict.items() python pandas?

Tags: pandas, performance, dictionary

I have a problem with performance with looping dictionary, because my dictionary data is so big. This is a small example of what my code look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'i': [1,2,3], 'old_col':['holly chicken','holly pen', 'holly']})
some_dict = {'.*chicken.*' : 'animal', '.*pen.*' : 'stuff'}
for k,v in some_dict.items():
    df.loc[df.old_col.str.contains(k),'new_col'] = v
```

The output is:

```
df.new_col

0    animal
1     stuff
2       NaN
Name: new_col, dtype: object
```

Is there any ways I can do to improve the performance, maybe vectorize it or not using loop?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from your dataframe and what problem you are trying to solve and your expected output so we can help?

Comment: @SaiKumar I updated my description.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217946/populating-pandas-dataframe-column-based-on-dictionary-of-regex

Comment: @Viktor It doesn't really return the values that I want. If I use this code df.loc[:,'new_col'] = df.old_col.replace(some_dict,regex=True) , It wouldn't return Nan values on index[2]