# Add column to dataframe using regex and dictionary

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have data as such:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10'], 
                    'amount': [10, 30, 40, 15, 20, 12, 55, 45, 60, 75], 
                    'description': [u'LYFT SAN FRANCISCO CA', u'XYZ STARBUCKS MINNEAPOLIS MN', u'HOLIDAY BEMIDJI MN', 
                                    u'MCDONALDS MADISON WI', u'ABC SUPERAMERICA MI', u'SUBWAY ROCHESTER MN', 
                                    u'NNT BURGER KING WI', u'UBER TRIP CA', u'superamerica CA', u'AMAZON NY']})
```

foo:

```
    id       amount description
    A1        10    LYFT SAN FRANCISCO CA
    A2        30    XYZ STARBUCKS MINNEAPOLIS MN
    A3        40    HOLIDAY BEMIDJI MN
    A4        15    MCDONALDS MADISON WI
    A5        20    ABC SUPERAMERICA MI
    A6        12    SUBWAY ROCHESTER MN
    A7        55    NNT BURGER KING WI
    A8        45    UBER TRIP CA
    A9        60    superamerica CA
    A10       75    AMAZON NY
```

I want to create a new column which categorizes each record based on a keyword match from the `description` column.

I have used help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43218023/5929443) answer to do it in the following way:

```
import re    
dict1 = {
    "LYFT" : "cab_ride",
    "UBER" : "cab_ride",
    "STARBUCKS" : "Food",
    "MCDONALDS" : "Food",
    "SUBWAY" : "Food",
    "BURGER KING" : "Food",
    "HOLIDAY" : "Gas",
    "SUPERAMERICA": "Gas"
        }

def get_category_from_desc(x):
    try:
        return next(dict1[k] for k in dict1 if re.search(k, x, re.IGNORECASE))
    except:
        return "Other"

foo['category'] = foo.description.map(get_category_from_desc)
```

This works but I want to ask if this is the best way out for this problem. Since I have a much larger set of keywords that can indicate a category, I have to create a huge dictionary:

```
dict1 = {
        "STARBUCKS" : "Food",
        "MCDONALDS" : "Food",
        "SUBWAY" : "Food",
        "BURGER KING" : "Food",
             .
             .
             .
        # ~50 more keys for "Food"

        "HOLIDAY" : "Gas",
        "SUPERAMERICA": "Gas",
             .
             .
             .
        # ~20 more keys for "Gas"

        "WALMART" : "grocery",
        "COSTCO": "grocery",
             .
             .
        # ..... ~30 more keys for "grocery"
             .
             .
        # ~ Many more categories with a large number of keys for each
}
```

**Edit**: I also want to know if there's a way out that does not require me to create a huge dictionary like the one shown above. Can I achieve this with a smaller data structure, something like:

```
dict2 = {
    "cab_ride" : ["LYFT", "UBER"], #....
    "food" : ["STARBUCKS", "MCDONALDS", "SUBWAY", "BURGER KING"], #....
    "gas" : ["HOLIDAY", "SUPERAMERICA"] #....
        }
```

Comment: As for your edit: probably not using a dict that looks like that...

Comment: So what should the dict look like?

Comment: It needs to be flat, unfortunately... `dict3 = {v: k for k, V in dict2.items() for v in V}`

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be achieved pretty easily using `df.replace` with regex-based replacement. You can then use `df.where` to handle "Other" cases.

```
dict2 = {rf'.*{k}.*': v for k, v in dict1.items()}

cats = foo['description'].replace(dict2, regex=True)
cats.where(cats != foo['description'], 'Other')

0    cab_ride
1        Food
2         Gas
3        Food
4         Gas
5        Food
6        Food
7    cab_ride
8       Other
9       Other
Name: description, dtype: object
```

---

Another option is using `str.extract` with `map`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict2 = defaultdict(lambda: 'Other')
dict2.update(dict1)

foo['description'].str.extract(rf"({'|'.join(dict1)})", expand=False).map(dict2)

0    cab_ride
1        Food
2         Gas
3        Food
4         Gas
5        Food
6        Food
7    cab_ride
8       Other
9       Other
Name: description, dtype: object
```

Comment: rf... nice  regular expression with f-string formatting.   Thanks for teaching me something new!  +1

Comment: @ScottBoston I only hope OP has python3.6... taking a gamble here :P

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.str` accessor with `extract` and a compiled regular expression using `join` on dictionary keys.

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10'], 
                    'amount': [10, 30, 40, 15, 20, 12, 55, 45, 60, 75], 
                    'description': [u'LYFT SAN FRANCISCO CA', u'XYZ STARBUCKS MINNEAPOLIS MN', u'HOLIDAY BEMIDJI MN', 
                                    u'MCDONALDS MADISON WI', u'ABC SUPERAMERICA MI', u'SUBWAY ROCHESTER MN', 
                                    u'NNT BURGER KING WI', u'UBER TRIP CA', u'superamerica CA', u'AMAZON NY']})


dict1 = {
    "LYFT" : "cab_ride",
    "UBER" : "cab_ride",
    "STARBUCKS" : "Food",
    "MCDONALDS" : "Food",
    "SUBWAY" : "Food",
    "BURGER KING" : "Food",
    "HOLIDAY" : "Gas",
    "SUPERAMERICA": "Gas"
        }

regstr = '(' + '|'.join(dict1.keys()) + ')'
foo['category'] = foo['description'].str.extract(regstr).squeeze().map(dict1).fillna('Other')
print(foo)
```

Output:

```
    id  amount                   description  category
0   A1      10         LYFT SAN FRANCISCO CA  cab_ride
1   A2      30  XYZ STARBUCKS MINNEAPOLIS MN      Food
2   A3      40            HOLIDAY BEMIDJI MN       Gas
3   A4      15          MCDONALDS MADISON WI      Food
4   A5      20           ABC SUPERAMERICA MI       Gas
5   A6      12           SUBWAY ROCHESTER MN      Food
6   A7      55            NNT BURGER KING WI      Food
7   A8      45                  UBER TRIP CA  cab_ride
8   A9      60               superamerica CA     Other
9  A10      75                     AMAZON NY     Other
```